# X-Editable Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I need to implement editable fields using the X-Editable jQuery plugin.

Currently I have a list of notes and on each note I need to have the ability to edit the title & content of each note.

Each note has a button that will toggle between on/off.

Everything works as expected except the fact that when the button is pressed the first time, nothing happens, the second time it enables, then it is like normal. I am guessing this has something to do with the inital field states, almost as if it is hardcoded that the first press will switch of editing.

Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Here is my code:

```
$('.edit').on('click', function(){
    var parent =    $( this).parents('div.note.card'),
        title =     $( parent ).find('.note-title'),
        content =   $( parent ).find('.note-content');

    $( title ).editable('toggleDisabled');
    $( content ).editable('toggleDisabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY using

```
 $('.note-title').editable('toggleDisabled');
$('.note-content').editable('toggleDisabled');
```

Instead of

```
 $( title ).editable('toggleDisabled');
$( content ).editable('toggleDisabled');
```